# Why might an Android Canvas fail to paint?

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint, draw

I've been asked to debug a problem in a large Android app. I was hoping someone here may know more about the Android rendering pipeline than I do.

Question:

What are the possible reasons why the Canvas supplied by Android might not actually paint anything? For example, are there any modes you can put it in to temporarily suspend paints?

Symptoms:

The app is responding correctly, but the first Activity that opens shows up blank. The entire application area is white, and the application's custom ActionBar is now showing up.

- The Views are laying out correctly (verified by using Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator)
- The main thread is responsive (verified by logging a heartbeat)
- The onDraw methods are being invoked (verified by putting breakpoints in various onDraw methods)
- The Views themselves seem to be painting correctly (verified by asking the root view to draw itself to a Bitmap and then serializing it to disk). The difference here is that this is drawing to a Canvas I instantiated myself rather than the one supplied by Android.
- None of the views are outside the screen bounds or have layers attached.
- Other Activities paint correctly.
- The misbehaving Activity makes use of Fragments.
- The problem was observed on both Android 4.3 and 4.4, and on several different devices.
- All of the relevant views are visible (verified by traversing the View hierarchy and checking getVisibility()).

I'm at a loss as to other things to check for. It looks as though everything is functioning correctly, except that anything that gets written to the Canvas is discarded. I would be delighted if anyone could offer any additional ideas for things to check for.

Also, the problem is not reproducible in the debugger - I only know about it from beta bug reports, none of which have supplied working steps to reproduce. I will need to fix this using code inspection and occasional customer bug reports.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not reproducible'?

Comment: Not reproducible on demand. Many beta users are encountering it, but the same user rarely encounters it twice. I can get data on this by pushing out diagnostic code to beta users but cannot reproduce it locally in the debugger. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: If drawing to your own canvas worked, try to disable hardware acceleration. 
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />

Comment: Thank you. That's something I haven't tried yet... and I guess if I push it to beta and don't get any new bug reports filed for a week or so, I could assume it fixed the problem. Now what would that tell me if it does or doesn't fix the issue? Where would I look next on this decision tree... ;-)